# Will Ubuntu 12.04 run on 128 MB of RAM

Tags: lenovo

I have a windows xp pc it has an intel celeron CPU and its about 700 MHz a19.1 GB HDD and 128 mb of ram 
What's the most modern version of Ubuntu that I can run

Comment: No version of Ubuntu is recommended as Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit needs 384MB.  Lubuntu 13.04 needs 128MB so should be OK and is supported here.

Comment: IMHO you should forget about graphical desktops and run your system on 12.04LTS-server as a headless server for file sharing or something similar.

Comment: [Bodhi Linux](http://www.bodhilinux.com/about_bodhi.php) is Ubuntu-based and requires `300+MHz CPU, 128MB RAM, and 2.5GB hard drive`. Used it on old computer. Uses [Enlightenment](http://www.bodhilinux.com/e17guide/e17guideEN/) as desktop. Before that, used [Damn SL](http://damnsmalllinux.org/) on a P1, but it's not updated. There is also Puppy, Vector, Knoppix, **Tiny Core**, [Tiny] Slitaz, more. Personally I would look for `LXDE` desktop today. In [this comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Linux_distributions#Live_media) the "RAM usage" gives you a hint, smaller better.

Comment: thinkwiki.de has a wiki page for old computers, includes [this list of minimum system requirements of suitable distros](http://thinkwiki.de/Linux_Distributionen_f%C3%BCr_%C3%A4ltere_Thinkpads#Ressourcenschonende_Linux_Distributionen). It also lists if they are Ubuntu or Debian based! (there is also this very long and very random [ubuntuforums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-478237-p-5.html) about linux and old computers, but reading this would be a hard task)